# Java - Working with Multitouch

Tags: java, multi-touch

I want to develop a multitouch application for my convertible with Java.

I could only find the MT4j (MultiTouch 4 Java) framework, but I would like to develop the multitouch structure aso on my own.

MT4j does not use or require any native libraries, so it must be possible: How do I use MultiTouch by using plain old Java?

Comment: Well. The MT4J is open source, so why don't you look at what they do to get an idea about the possibilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multi-touch is not available in AWT/Swing, but it is supported in [JavaFX 2.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/gestures.htm#CHDDHFJJ)

As far as I understand, the MT4j library **does** use native libraries (see the .dll and .so files in the download).